# Why are unicode characters treated the same in C++ std::string?

Tags: c++, unicode

Here's an Ideone: http://ideone.com/vjByty.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main() {
    string s = "\u0001\u0001";
    cout << s.length() << endl;
    if (s[0] == s[1]) {
        cout << "equal\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused on so many levels.

What does it mean when I type in an escaped Unicode string literal in my C++ program?

Shouldn't it take 4 bytes for 2 characters? (assuming utf-16)

Why are the first two characters of `s` (first two bytes) equal?

Comment: It is probably compiler and operating system specific. And also depending on the version of the C++ standard. BTW, your assumption "utf-16" is often false.

Comment: Could it be using a utf-8?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch not *often* false, *always* false. Unless you use the leading `L` on the string literal, then I suppose it's *often*. But that's not what we have here.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I only know Linux (and knew other Unixen like SunOS & HPUX from previous century), on which it ("utf-16") is false. But I don't know Windows at all....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch for Windows a wide string will be UTF-16, it is true. But this code doesn't contain any wide strings!

Comment: @MarkRansom Not necessarily always false.  A platform could have 16 bit `char`, with the UTF-16 as the basic execution character set.  (I don't know of any that do, but the standard definitely allows it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, the standard is flexible enough to allow it. But without a concrete example, I'm sticking by my statement.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've not seen it because I don't work in fields where such implementations may occur.  But there definitely are implementations with 32 bit char, and probably 16 bit char as well.  And why wouldn't they use UTF-16 or UTF-32 as the native execution character set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the draft C++11 standard says the following about universal characters in narrow string literals (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> Escape sequences and universal-character-names in non-raw string literals have the same meaning as in
>   character literals (2.14.3), except that the single quote [...] In a narrow string literal, a universal-charactername
>   **may map to more than one char element** due to multibyte encoding

and includes the following note:

> The size of a narrow string literal is the total
>   number of escape sequences and other characters, **plus at least one for the multibyte encoding** of each
>   universal-character-name, plus one for the terminating ’\0’.

Section `2.14.3` referred to above says:

> A universal-character-name is translated to the encoding, in the appropriate execution character set, of the
>   character named. If there is no such encoding, the universal-character-name is translated to an implementation defined
>   encoding.

if I try this example (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VydzXDy4NBE7aWpS)*):

```
string s = "\u0F01\u0001";
```

The first universal character does map to multiple characters.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean when I type in an escaped Unicode string literal in my C++ program?

To quote the standard:

> A universal-character-name is translated to the encoding, in the appropriate execution character set, of the character named. If there is no such encoding, the universal-character-name is translated to an implementation-defined encoding.

Typically, the execution character set will be ASCII, which contains a character with value 1. So `\u0001` will be translated into a single character with value 1.

If you were to specify non-ASCII characters, like `\u263A`, you might see more than one byte per character.

> Shouldn't it take 4 bytes for 2 characters? (assuming utf-16)

If it were UTF-16, yes. But `string` can't be encoded with UTF-16, unless `char` has 16 bits, which it usually doesn't. UTF-8 is a more likely encoding, in which characters with values up to 127 (that is, the whole ASCII set) are encoded with a single byte.

> Why are the first two characters of s (first two bytes) equal?

With the above assumptions, they are both the character with value 1.

Comment: I don't know that UTF-8 is more likely.  But even with other encodings (like ISO 8859-1), `'\u0001'` will translate into a single byte.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, if the execution character set includes 1 (which it will if it's ASCII or a superset), then `\u0001` must translate to a single byte, as the answer says. Perhaps "more likely" was a poor choice of words, since apparently there are some quaint systems that still use 8-bit encodings. But I've no idea what they might do with arbitrary Unicode points, and don't really want to know.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake in the Ideone. Here's one with string :`\u0001\u0000`. http://ideone.com/N6KkHt Both the characters are still treated as identical. They should both be treated as ascii and that means they should be treated as 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: @batman: That's a GCC bug, `\u0000` is incorrectly translated to 1. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53690

Comment: @MikeSeymour what a coincidence :P

Comment: It's the "more likely" I'm unsure about.  The last time I tested, both VS and g++ effectively used ISO 8859-1.  That wasn't very recently, however, and it's possible that they've corrected this.  (Like you, I believe that the "correct" solution today should be UTF-8 for 8 bit characters, UTF-16 for 16 bit and UTF-32 for 32 bit.)

Comment: @batman I don't know if its really a coincidence.  I suspect rather that someone didn't want any universal character name to be the end of string.  (In other words, I'm fairly sure that this behavior was intentional, and was originally thought to be a feature, not a bug.  You'll have to remember that things like universal character names are fairly new, and although the situation has improved a lot in the last couple of years, there's not a lot of experience as a basis for what is "best practice".)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Modernish GCC (at least for Linux) uses UTF-8, and I don't particular care what woes Microsoft choose to inflict on their victims. In any case, UTF-8 is "more likely" than UTF-16 in a narrow string literal, since the latter can't be used be used with 8-bit bytes. As my answer says.